# Does master cluster accept requests when child workers are busy

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `cluster` module to create child processes/workers. Here is the simple setup that I have:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    cluster.fork();
} else {
    http.createServer((req, res) => {
        if (cluster.isMaster) {
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end('hello from master\n');
        } else {
            while (true) {
                console.log('from child');
            }
        }
    }).listen(8484);
}
```

I wanted to know, whether the main process processes requests if a child process is busy. So I ran the above code and made two requests from a browser, expecting that the first one will make child process busy and the second process will be processed by the master cluster. But I never got `hello from master` sent to the client.

So does master process/worker/cluster handle requests if child processes are busy? And if so, why my experiment didn't work?

Comment: Would your issue have anything to do with your if/else statement? When it reaches the else, `cluster.isMaster` is not true, so your first nested if never passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that the masters only job is managing children. Your experiment didn't work because your server code is only getting setup inside a child, as written, so all requests against them will be against child processes

Comment: thanks, I tried rewriting the script so that `createServer` is executed in master and child cluster, and I get the error `Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:8484`. So as I understand the same port can't be used for multiple `listen`. However, if I use 4 child processes and all of them execute the same code, how it's working in that case?

Comment: Because as I said, the cluster master is supposed to only manage the children. It proxies and exposes the declared port that the children expose to appear as one interface.

Comment: ok, thanks, so then as I understand I'd better separate child cluster code and do like this `if (cluster.isMaster) {
    cluster.fork();
} else {
    require('./child');
}`. Makes sense?